# How do I show that something is a pmf without calculating individual probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was told that a discrete probability distribution is defined as $f(x)=log_{10}\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)$ and the support are the numbers $1,2,3,...,9$. I was asked to show that this is indeed a probabiilty mass function but without calculating any individual probabilities. I am stuck on how to do this. I know the four rules on what defines a pmf but I'm still a little unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe, that $f(x) = \log_{10}(x+1) - \log_{10}(x)$, and hence $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in the domain, and that
$$
   \sum_{x=1}^9 f(x) = \sum_{x=1}^9\left( \log_{10}(x+1) - \log_{10}(x) \right) = {\color\green{\log_{10}(2)}} - \log_{10}(1) + \log_{10}(3) - {\color\green{\log_{10}(2)}} + \cdots + \log_{10}(10) - \log_{10}(9) = \log_{10}(10) - \log_{10}(1) = 1 - 0 = 1
$$
hence $f(x)$ has total mass of 1.

As a side remark, the distribution defined by this PMF is known as [Benford law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law).

Comment: Ah I see, I'm a little rusty on the log base 10 rules. Thanks!